# Is there a way to get the Kubernetes version using Prometheus API?

Tags: api, kubernetes, version, prometheus

I have tried this metric cadvisor_version_info and I can get dockerVersion but no kubernetes version info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With prometheus you shoul be able to get the info of your cluster using the **kubernetes_build_info** metric.

Comment: this is what I am looking for